# Determining if this collection of sets is a topology on the real numbers?

Tags: general-topology

Let $\tau$ consist of $\mathbb{R}$, $\emptyset$ and every interval $[-r, r]$, for $r$ any positive irrational number.

i) $\mathbb{R}, \emptyset$ are in $\tau$

ii) $[-r_1, r_1] \bigcup [-r_2, r_2] \bigcup ... = [-r_k, r_k]$ where $r_k =$ max$\{r_i\}, i = 1, 2, ...$

iii) $[-r_1, r_1] \bigcap [-r_2, r_2] = [-r_k, r_k]$ where $r_k =$ min$\{r_1, r_2\}$

But I have a feeling this is wrong as I have read somewhere that this is not a topology. So what am I missing?

Comment: You are assuming that there is a max to those $r_k$, which need not be the case.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I have read that $(-r, r)$, for $r$ any positive real number is a topology so assuming that's correct, the fact that there is no max to the $r_k$ doesn't make a difference.

Comment: It makes all the difference, since a union of an infinite number of closed intervals can become open, while the reverse is not true.

Comment: (well, perhaps not all the difference, as using open intervals would still fail to be a topology if you restrict to irrational or rational end-points).

Comment: Remember that a topology is closed under **arbitrary unions**, that is even infinite. You are proving that $\tau$ is closed under finite unions.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Consider a sequence of irrational numbers $r_i$ monotonically increasing and with limit $1$.

What is $\bigcup_{i\to\infty}[-r_i,r_i]$?

Comment: Or even just $\bigcup_{0<r<1}[-r,r]$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen He needs them to be irrational to have them in the proposed topology here.

Comment: $(-1, 1)$? And hence it is not in $\tau$ so $\tau$ is not a topology?

Comment: @sonicboom right